# 404 Error when attaching image to GitLab Wiki Page

Tags: docker, gitlab, csrf

We have a self-hosted GitLab server running within a Docker container, and everything looks to be working properly with the exception of attaching images (and presumably any file) to a project Wiki page. In the WebUI it reports a `404 Project Not Found` error after attempting to attach the image, and digging into the log files I can see the following:

```
Started POST "/api/v4/projects/124/wikis/attachments" for <my-ip> at 2024-01-24 12:36:21 +0000

Processing by Gitlab::RequestForgeryProtection::Controller#index as JSON

Parameters: {"file.name"=>"image.png", "file.path"=>"/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/uploads/tmp/image.png485432037", "file.size"=>"44057", "file.md5"=>"<md5>", "file.sha1"=>"<sha1>", "file.sha256"=>"<sha256>", "file.sha512"=>"<sha512>", "file"=>#<UploadedFile:0x00007f7f42950a38 @tempfile=#<File:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads/tmp/image.png485432037>, @size=44057, @content_type="application/octet-stream", @original_filename="image.png", @sha256="<sha256>", @remote_id=nil>}

Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.

This CSRF token verification failure is handled internally by `GitLab::RequestForgeryProtection`

Unlike the logs may suggest, this does not result in an actual 422 response to the user

For API requests, the only effect is that `current_user` will be `nil` for the duration of the request

Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)
```

From what I've been able to determine online, then the CSRF is used to ensure that the client is talking to the expected host, which makes me think that the CSRF token is out of sync?

To give some history, this only seems to have started happening after we migrated from one server to another:

- A new host server was stood up and the GitLab "runtime" files were copied from old server to new server
- Docker image/container was recreated on the new server using the copied "runtime" files and by running the same docker command from the original server

As best as I can tell, everything else looks to be working. Can perform remote Git operations (via command line as well as IDE), can create/modify/delete Wiki pages, and can perform the expected project manipulations via the WebUI. Only the attaching images to a wiki page seems to not work...